# Prove that succession generated from an iterative function, converges to the root of the function.

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

The problem of finding the root of the function $f(x)$, i.e. the value of $x^{\ast}$ such that $f(x^{\ast}) = 0$, can be reformulated as $x = g(x)$, and therefore the root $x^{\ast}$ will be the value $x^{\ast} = g(x^{\ast})$. Where:

- $g(x)$ is the *Iterative Function*;
- $x^{\ast}$ is *fixed point* of $g(x)$

With this reformulation, it is possible to approximate the root $x^{\ast}$, through an iterative procedure as:
$$x_{k+1} = g(x_k), \qquad k=0,1, \ldots$$
with $x_0$ assigned with an initial value.

**Theorem**:

> If $g(x) : [a,b] → \mathbb R$ continuous and such that $a \le g(x) \le b \quad \forall x \in [a,b] \Rightarrow \exists $ a fixed point $x^{\ast} \in [a,b]$.
> Also, if $g(x)$ is derivable in $[a,b]$, and $\exists \, 0 < \rho <1$ such that $|g'(x)| \le \rho \forall x  \in (a,b)$ then the fixed point is unique and the succession generated from $x_{k+1} = g(x_k)$  converges to $x^{\ast}$.

**Proof:**

We prove only the last part, about the convergence. Since $x^{\ast}$ is a *fixed point* of $g(x)$, and therefore $x^{\ast} = g(x^{\ast})$, we have:

$$\begin{array}{l}
|x_{k+1} - x^{\ast}| 
& \overset{1}{=} & |g(x_k) - g(x^{\ast})| \\
& \overset{2}{=} & |g \big (x^{\ast} + \left (x_{k} - x^{\ast} \right ) \big ) - g(x^{\ast})| \\
& \overset{3}{=} & |g'(c_k)|\cdot |x_k - x^{\ast}|
\end{array}
$$

we applied *Taylor series*, and $c_k \in I(x_k, x^{\ast})$, where $I(x_k, x^{\ast})$ is the interval containing $x_k$ and $x^{\ast}$.

Since $|g'(c_k)| \le \rho$ then we have:

$$|x_{k+1} - x^{\ast}| \le \rho|x_k - x^{\ast}|$$

and applying many times this inequality we obtain:

$$|x_k - x^{\ast}| \le \rho^k |x_0 - x^{\ast}| $$

and therefore:

$$\underset{k → \infty}{\lim} |x_k - x^{\ast}| \le \underset{k → \infty}{\lim} \rho^k |x_0 - x^{\ast}| = 0$$

and the convergence is verified.  $\square$

---

The above is from my textbook, it is the suggested proof, but I don't understand (for now), what is the reasoning applied in the passages from $\overset{2}{=}$ to $\overset{3}{=}$.

Please, can you help me to understand? Many thanks!

edit: (Probably, it is weird a proof, so if you think a different proof is better than this, you can post it but with detailed passages. Thanks.)

Comment: I don't think equation 2 is true as written, can you check? Shouldn't there be two $g$'s?

Comment: I also don't understand equation $2$. It should just be $|g(x_k)-g(x^*)|=|g'(c_k)||x_k-x^*|$, this is just the mean value theorem.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith sorry, corrected.

Comment: Even after you corrected it I don't see why this step is necessary. Why just not use the mean value theorem immediately?

Comment: @Mark if you are sure about that, can you show me your passages? Thanks!

Comment: Let me say that it is important to prove that theorem, but if you think a different proof is better, post it with details.

Comment: It's not a different proof, what I'm saying is that we can immediately say that $g(x_k)-g(x^*)=g'(c_k)(x_k-x^*)$ for some $c_k$, this is just the mean value theorem. The rest of the proof is the same.

Comment: @Mark - the reference to Taylor series makes it seem the textbook is invoking Taylor's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder), of which the mean value theorem is a special case, to get from equation 2 to 3. It seems they want to write $x_k$ in the form $x^*+h$ in order to emphasize that the Taylor expansion is being taken about $x^*$. Still, I agree it would probably have been less confusing just to invoke the mean value theorem to get straight from equation 1 to 3.

Comment: @Mark Please, can you post as answer your explanation, with details? And also, if possible, please can you explain me the passages till the end of the proof? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll explain the proof. We are going to use the mean value theorem. It says that if a function $f$ is differentiable in an interval $(a,b)$ and continuous in $[a,b]$ then there exists a point $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$.

Now, in the theorem we want to prove we know that $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and that $x^*$ is a fixed point of $g$. Also, $g$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$ and $|g'(x)|\leq\rho$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. So using the mean value theorem we know that for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a point $c_k$ between $x_k$ and $x^*$ such that $g(x_k)-g(x^*)=g'(c_k)(x_k-x^*)$. Hence, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:

$|x_{k+1}-x^*|=|g(x_k)-g(x^*)|=|g'(c_k)||x_k-x^*|\leq\rho |x_k-x^*|$

Note that this is true for every $k$. Hence we conclude that:

$|x_k-x^*|\leq\rho|x_{k-1}-x^*|\leq\rho^2|x_{k-2}-x^*|\leq...\leq\rho^k|x_0-x^*|$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Since $0<\rho<1$ we know that $\rho^k|x_0-x^*|\to 0$ when $k\to\infty$. And since $0\leq |x_k-x^*|\leq\rho^k|x_0-x^*|$ the squeeze theorem tells us that $x_k\to x^*$.

Comment: why we consider $x_k \le c_k \le x^{\ast}$ instead of $a \le c_k \le b$?

Comment: Because we aim to bound $|g(x_k)-g(x^*)|$, not $|g(b)-g(a)|$. So we are using the mean value theorem in the interval $[x_k, x^*]$.

Comment: multiplying in every passage with that $0 < \rho < 1$ we obtain a distance getting shorter.

Comment: in $|x_{k+1} - x^{\ast}| \le \rho |x_k - x^{\ast}|$ we are saying that the distance from the root in the next iteration, i.e. in $(k+1)$, it is **for sure** shorter than the current iteration, i.e. in $(k)$, and then we can extend for every $k$ till $0$.

Comment: it would be possible to have a graphic example?